# Please help identify a fanfic-y apocryphal story based on Noon Universe

Tags: identification-request, russian-language, strugatsky-brothers, apocryphal-works

I've been trying to find this one for several years but somehow Google-fu was weak.

- Pretty old - I think I read it in early/mid 90s. Internet-published.
- Apocryphal mishmash of entire Noon universe
- Very specific plot detail that can serve as litmus test remains in my memory - they had some sort of galactic defence firedrill, involving two star cruisers named after dinosaurs (I think one was Stegosaurus).
- somewhat predictably, it was written in Russian

Comment: I think we will need a bit more information.

Comment: I'm sure there's more you can remember: which parts of the Noon universe were involved? Are we talking from _Land of Crimson Clouds_ till the end?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - mostly it was later stuff (Kammerer, Komov and on)

Comment: Never read it, unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you add more information? See also the tips in http://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info.

Comment: @Shokhet - out of the 6 specific bullet points in the tag Wiki info, I already covered 5 (and one missing one was kind of obvious, that it was in Russian, but I added it explicitly now). Unfortunately, I don't remember any additional details.

Comment: @Shokhet The question already covers (1) The age of the story (2)  Time when the story was read - both are early/mid 90s; (3) Medium - Internet; (4) Location (5) The appearance of the book (#4/5 are n/a, since it was internet-published). I added language.

Comment: @DVK My apologies; you are correct. I don't know why, but the question still feels a little...thin. Do you have more details about the story? (Also, thanks for adding the language; now I know that it's absolutely pointless for me to try to look for this story)

Comment: @Shokhet - i have general plot details; but in all honesty nothing that can aid searcheability.

Comment: Okay. Good luck! I hope you find what you're looking for :)

Comment: Any plot detail could jog someone's memory. Do you think that story was published professionally or only online? Do you think it's likely to have been translated into English?

Comment: @Gilles - Back when I read it, it was definitely only online. I don't know if it was later included in any anthology (there were several anthologies published of Strugatsky derived apocryphia; I read some but not all). I'm not aware of any of this being tranlsated, including the story I read, and the overwhelming chances are, it wasn't.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the title? [There's a list](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/xumor/xumor00.htm) of such works, maybe you could find it there. Not many of them are electronically published though.